# firefox debugging protocol sendHTTPRequest error

Tags: firefox, websocket, remote-debugging, firefox-developer-tools

I started the debugging protocol on websocket and sent this command :

```
{ "to": "server1.conn13.child1/consoleActor2", "type": "sendHTTPRequest", "request": { "url": "https://facebook.com", "method": "GET", "headers": [{ "name": "referer", "value": "google.com" } ] } }
```

but I got :

```
{"error":"unknownError","message":"error occurred while processing 'sendHTTPRequest: [Exception... \"Failed to open input source 'https://facebook.com/'\"  nsresult: \"0x805e0006 (<unknown>)\"  location: \"JS frame :: resource://devtools/shared/base-loader.js -> resource://devtools/server/actors/webconsole.js :: onSendHTTPRequest :: line 1697\"  data: yes]\nStack: onSendHTTPRequest@resource://devtools/shared/base-loader.js -> resource://devtools/server/actors/webconsole.js:1697:5\nonPacket@resource://devtools/shared/base-loader.js -> resource://devtools/server/main.js:1792:15\nreceiveMessage@resource://devtools/shared/base-loader.js -> resource://devtools/shared/transport/transport.js:761:7\nLine: 1697, column: 0"}
```